After successful payment in PayPal, I want to implement this command
I want to be automatically redirected to another page after successful payment.
<div id="paypal-container-CSD5FA"></div>
<script>paypal.HostedButtons({hostedButtonId: "CSD5FA",}).render("#paypal-container-CSD5FA")</script>   
<?include 't.php';
?>


Edit your button at www.paypal.com/buttons and set the "Thank You" page to the full path to t.php

On the PayPal site, it is transferred to a page on my site, but I don’t want it to be executed directly from the same code. After the payment process is completed, it is transferred directly.

I don't know what you are saying, but the above is the mechanism that can be used. There isn't another, not unless you want to do a full frontend+backend standard integration https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/
